# make directory permission denied

Tags: cmake, ubuntu-make

```
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/nabi/fftw-3.3.8/api'
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/nabi/fftw-3.3.8/api'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'install-exec-am'.
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/include'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 fftw3.h fftw3.f fftw3l.f03 fftw3q.f03 '/usr/local/include'
/usr/bin/install: cannot create regular file '/usr/local/include/fftw3.h': Permission denied
/usr/bin/install: cannot create regular file '/usr/local/include/fftw3.f': Permission denied
/usr/bin/install: cannot create regular file '/usr/local/include/fftw3l.f03': Permission denied
/usr/bin/install: cannot create regular file '/usr/local/include/fftw3q.f03': Permission denied
Makefile:566: recipe for target 'install-includeHEADERS' failed
make[3]: *** [install-includeHEADERS] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/nabi/fftw-3.3.8/api'
Makefile:705: recipe for target 'install-am' failed
make[2]: *** [install-am] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/nabi/fftw-3.3.8/api'
Makefile:699: recipe for target 'install' failed
make[1]: *** [install] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/nabi/fftw-3.3.8/api'
Makefile:708: recipe for target 'install-recursive' failed
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

Previous command

```
./configure
make
make install
```

Comment: `make install` needs root permission `sudo make install`

Answer (score 2):

You need to execute `sudo make install`, instead of just `make install`.